# Looking for JavaScript library that can perform string replacements like the following:

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Need a library that can perform the expected output

```
var subReddit = "reactjs";
var url = "http://www.reddit.com/r/${subReddit}.json";

// url should be "http://www.reddit.com/r/reactjs.json";
```

Is this something that is ReactJs only, or generic? Anyone know what library can do this?

Answer (score -1):

Blah... found it moments after I post it: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/template_strings.